# Mongo Error: must have $meta projection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm sorry if this is duplicate question, but I didn't find solution.

However... I'm trying to make text search in mongodb.[Like this ($meta)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/)

I've made indexes for fields in my collection, marked as "text". But I have following error:

```
MongoError: must have $meta projection for all $meta sort keys
```

Here is the code:

```
var query = {
    description : {
        $regex : new RegExp('\^\.\*(' + ('abaaba|abadaba|woobydooby') + ')\.\*\$', 'g', 'i')
    }
};
var sort = { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } };
var limit = 50;     

Collection
    .find(query)
    .sort(sort)
    .limit(limit)
    .exec(function (err, records) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(records);
        }
    });
```

Where I made a mistake?

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
Node v. 8.9.4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include a score $meta project to your query like so:

```js
var query = {
  description : {
     $regex : new RegExp('\^\.\*(' + ('abaaba|abadaba|woobydooby') + ')\.\*\$', 'g', 'i')
  },
  {
    score : {$meta : "textScore" }
  }
};
```

Comment: Nope, I've already tried to do with such way, still the same error.

Comment: Oh! I've got it! You have invalid object in query but the point of query is correct. Request to DB should looks like `Collection.find({field: "value"}, { score: { $meta: 'textScore' } })` (2 objects in one brackets).

@Thankgod Ossaija fix your answer and I mark it as correct

Comment: Hey, @Merge-pony, glad you get the gist of my answer, I don't see the invalid object you are referring to, I just took the query from your question and added a projection object to it. Can you be more specific please!